# Ubuntu на ноут, проблема с WiFi

Tags: wifi, ubuntu

В общем, ставил я себе на ноутбук Lenovo B570, операционную систему ubuntu версии 11.10 (последняя на данный момент), установил удачно, все вроде бы ок. Но вот не включается wifi, что я только не делал, и в биосе включал/выключал, и на корпусе, и сочетанием клавиш fn + f5, и в настройках самой ubuntu, и пере устанавливал ОС и драйвера ставил, но ничего не помогает. В общем, может у кого-то была подобная проблема, помогите!

Есть ли смысл попробовать установить другую версию ubuntu? Посоветуйте проверенную, стабильную версию ubuntu которой вы пользовались или пользуетесь.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Это помогло:

1. Открываешь терминал
2. Вводишь `sudo -s`
3. Вводишь пароль
4. Пишешь `echo "blacklist acer_wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
5. Перезагружаешь ноут
6. Подключаешь wi-fi

Появился еще один вопрос. Изначально была установлена ОС Windows 7, после чего был установлен последний дистрибутив ubuntu 11.10. Так вот, при запуске ноута нету выбора для запуска между убунту и виндой, сразу запускается убунту, не могу зайти в винду. (образ с ubuntu записывал на [флешку](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

Как зайти в винду?

Comment: Попробуйте `sudo update-grub`, затем `sudo reboot`.P.S. На этом форум всегда надо задавать вопрос в новой теме.

Answer (score 0):

Делаем по шагам. Устанавливаем

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic
```

Перезагружаемся. Смотрим, запустилось ли? Нет, тогда выполняем

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

Смотрим, есть ли строка "acer-wireless: Wireless LAN"? Есть, тогда выполняем

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmisudo echo "blacklist acer-wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Перезагружаемся, жмем F2, F5, F9, чтобы сбросить настройки биос.

Answer (score 0):

Знакомый мой тоже жаловался, что в этой версии плохо дела с Wi-Fi. Если достучусь до него, то дополню ответ.Когда я пользовался убунту 10.10 никаких подобных проблем не наблюдал.

Answer (score 0):

soft [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/moinmoin/Wicd%20on%20Ubuntu) мне помогло

Answer (score 0):

У меня установлен Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx).

Сначала устанавливал пакет Wi-fi Radar, после этого не было проблем.А сейчас (почему-то) "ловит" Wi-fi-сигнал **сам, автоматически**, только (что естественно) спрашивает пароль!

Устанавливал Ubuntu 11.10. Мне лично не понравилась. Слишком все "наворочено".

Итог: установил себе 10.04, тем более, что она LTS (long term support), т.е. имеет законную длительную поддержку.

Рекомендую всем.